# Gradle: exclude external dependency (lib) from release build

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

i wanted to get rid of unnecessary debug dependencies (e.g. stetho) in release builds.

I tried to utilize variant source sets (src/debug vs. src/release) which is working fine in general.
But i have the following case:

app (uses my network lib)

network lib (has dependency to stetho - uses variant source sets to exclude stetho from release builds)

thing is. the library is always published in the release variant. so if i build my app in debug variant and do not build the lib locally as well it does not work.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems there is no real solution for that. Currently it's not possible to propagate variants. See: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36967265